# Django REST Framework: restrict data records access to the users created them

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, user-permissions, database-permissions

I'm trying to figure out, what is the best way to manage model access permissions with Django.

I have a table of items which belong to the users created them. All the items a managed via a RESTful API. When using this API I want to limit access to the items created by a given user.

Do I have to create several tables or is it possible to achieve the same with just one table?
If I have to use multiple tables, how do I correlate API requests with a particular table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to do it via both API and admin. This basically resembles Rob's idea.

First of all, every time I create a new user via admin panel, I need to append a user to my items:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if getattr(obj, 'user', None) is None:
            obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()

admin.site.register(MyItem, MyAdmin)
```

Then when accessing my model, I just filter by user (which is btw a foreign key to django.contrib.auth.models.User):

```
MyItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Finally to make it work with Django REST Framework, I need to add a couple of methods to My custom ModelViewSet:

```
class MyItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = MyItem
    serializer_class = MyItemSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return MyItem.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.user = self.request.user
```

I've used documentation and (lots) trial and error to figure this out.

Comment: That demonstrates how much the DRF's documentation was useful.

Answer (score 0):

if you want generic object-level permissions then you can use a permission backend like [django-guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian), [here](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions#djangomodelpermissions) is examples for integrating with django-restframework

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `created_by` field on your objects. Then compare the django `user` to that.
It's a little difficult help further without a concrete example.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Like how would you generate that field and how exactly you would compare the user when sending a HTTP request?

Answer (score 0):

Using django-rest-framework and django-rest-auth, I had to perform additional steps as described in the answer by Lucas Weyne to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54171931/django-auth-self-request-user-is-always-anonymous-in-viewset).

Here's what he suggested that worked for me.

Make sure to include the authorization token in the request:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b" <url>
```

This is key because otherwise the server doesn't know who the user is.

Add this to your viewset definition:

```
permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, ]
```

This is important if the query is user dependent.