# Django auth: self.request.user is always Anonymous in viewset

Tags: django, authentication, filter, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I'm trying to make the server only return documents which were created by the logged-in user. I'm following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529529/django-rest-framework-restrict-data-records-access-to-the-users-created-them) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35581292/how-to-filter-user-related-records-with-permissions-in-django-rest-framework/35593315) but the logged in user is returned as "Anonymous".

I am using Django Rest Framework with Django Rest Auth, and a custom user, but no other customisations.

Django 2.0.10

Here is my viewset in api.py:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions

from .models import List, Item
from .serializers import ListSerializer, ItemSerializer


class ListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # queryset = List.objects.all()
    # permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny, ]
    model = List
    serializer_class = ListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        print(self.request.user)
        return List.objects.filter(created_by=self.request.user)

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.created_by = self.request.user
```

Settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'

# django rest auth
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
```

I've read other posts about this issue which all talk about custom middleware, but I haven't created a custom middleware unless django-rest-framework or django-rest-auth is actually such a thing? And the posts don't seem to show how to get the user  in the viewset.

Also the posts are old, so Django has probably changed.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240832/django-and-middleware-which-uses-request-user-is-always-anonymous) I tried the following, it did not work:

```
class ListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # queryset = List.objects.all()
    # permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny, ]
    model = List
    serializer_class = ListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        print(self.request.user)
        self.request.custom_prop = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_actual_value(self.request))
        print(self.request.custom_prop)
        return List.objects.filter(created_by=self.request.user)

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.created_by = self.request.user
```

I'd be very grateful for any help. This is such a basic requirement, it ought to be simple but I'm absolutely stuck.

Edit: in case it helps somebody else, below is my working code based on Lucas Weyne's answer. I extended the logic so the user sees all Lists they created, AND all lists that have the flag "is_public", but can only modify lists they created.

I have set permissions.AllowAny because I want users who are not logged in to see public lists. In the client code, I check whether the user is logged in, and if they are I send the token in the query header.

Note the use of the Q object which is the easiest way I could find to return records that satisfy either of the two conditions. I couldn't find any mention of the Q object in the [Django rest framework docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/). I eventually found it in the [main Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/).

This all seems to work but if you spot something I've done wrong, please comment! I am not sure if this is the Django way to approach the requirement but I like the fact that the permissions logic is all in one place.

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions
from .models import List
from .serializers import ListSerializer
from django.db.models import Q


class ListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    ViewSet for lists. Before allowing any operation, the user's status is checked.

    Anybody can view a public list.
    A logged-in user can create lists.
    A logged-in user can view, edit and delete the lists they created.
    """
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny, ]
    model = List
    serializer_class = ListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        # restrict any method that can alter a record
        restricted_methods = ['POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        if self.request.method in restricted_methods:
            # if you are not logged in you cannot modify any list
            if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
              return List.objects.none()

            # you can only modify your own lists
            # only a logged-in user can create a list and view the returned data
            return List.objects.filter(created_by=self.request.user)

        # GET method (view list) is available to owner and for public lists
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
          if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return List.objects.filter(is_public__exact=True)

          return List.objects.filter(Q(created_by=self.request.user) | Q(is_public__exact=True))

        # explicitly refuse any non-handled methods
        return List.objects.none()

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.created_by = self.request.user
```

Comment: *Is* the user actually logged in? If so how was that done?

Comment: Thanks! As it turns out, your question gets to the root of the problem. The user had logged in successfully with django-rest-auth but I had forgotten to send the authorization Token with the request. I am still getting used to token authentication and forgot that without it, the user is not authenticated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For clients to authenticate via `TokenAuthentication`, the token key should be included in the `Authorization` HTTP header. Browseable API is only able to pass user credentials  through Basic or Session authentication. To test your API, you'll need a HTTP client like [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/)

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b" <url>
```

Allow any access to your view will raise an internal server error at `List.objects.filter(created_by=self.request.user)` for unauthorized users instead `401 Unauthorized`. If the queryset is user dependant, you should add a permission class to require user credentials.

```
class ListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, ]
    serializer_class = ListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return List.objects.filter(created_by=self.request.user)

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.created_by = self.request.user
```

Comment: Thank you! Following your instructions to add the permission class and send the authorization token with the request, works perfectly.

Comment: I have a follow-up question, if  you have any thoughts please? I have another model, Item. Items are associated with Lists by means of models.ForeignKey. Do I need to manage permissions for Items manually or will they inherit from Lists?

Comment: I have added my final code with multiple conditions to the question, in case it helps anybody else.